# Multiple checkbox value checking and updated table data as a result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to write a script to work with two groups of checkboxes, where the script handles the options from both sets and shows/hide rows of table data based on this.

What should happen is that you filter the table rows whenever you update the values in either set of checkboxes. The rows that remain should follow the logic of BOTH sets of checkboxes each time a change occurs in the selections from either set.

I am really stumped as to how you can make both sets work together, any pointers would be great please?

```html
<form name="repaymentcalc" id="calcform" action="">

<section id="type">

  <p id="Mortgage Type">Mortgage Type</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t2" id="t2" checked/>Type 2<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t3" id="t3" checked/>Type 3<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t5" id="t5" checked/>Type 5<br>

</section>

<section id="fee">

  <p id="Fee">Fee</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="fee" id="fee" checked/>Fee<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="nofee" id="nofee" checked/>No Fee<br>

</section>

</form>

<table id="mortgagetable">
    
<thead>

<tr class="producthd"><th class="lenderhd">Lender</th><th class="typehd">Type</th><th class="feehd">Fee (£)</th></tr>

</thead>

<tbody>

<tr class="product"><td class="lender">Bank One<td class="t2">Type 2</td><td class="fee">1000</td></tr>
<tr class="product"><td class="lender">Bank Two<td class="t3">Type 3</td><td class="nofee">None</td></tr>
<tr class="product"><td class="lender">Bank Three<td class="t5">Type 4</td><td class="nofee">None</td></tr>

</tbody>

</table>

</html>
```

Comment: on which event you are calling this function **MortgageTypeCheckbox()**

Comment: are you really missing the calls to your js-functions and the eventhandlers or is there just some code missing in your js? please add then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would handle this by dynamically generating the table, and when the radios are changed just re-render it.

```js
var lenders = [{
  name: "Bank 1",
  type: "Type 2",
  fee: 0
}, {
  name: "Bank 2",
  type: "Type 3",
  fee: 0
}, {
  name: "Bank 3",
  type: "Type 5",
  fee: 1000
}];

function renderLenders() {
  var types = $("input[name=type]:checked").map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
  }).get();
  var fees = $("input[name=fee]:checked").map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
  }).get();

  var l = lenders.filter(function(item, index, array) {
    return types.indexOf(item.type) != -1;
  });

  l = l.filter(function(item, index, array) {
    return (
      (
        item.fee > 0 &&
        fees.indexOf("fee") != -1
      ) ||
      (
        item.fee == 0 &&
        fees.indexOf("nofee") != -1
      )
    );
  });

  var rows = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
    rows += "<tr><td>" + l[i].name + "</td><td>" + l[i].type + "</td><td>" + ((l[i].fee > 0) ? l[i].fee : "None") + "</td></tr>";
  }
  $("#lenders").html(rows);
}
$(function(){
  renderLenders();
  $("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function(){
    renderLenders();
  });
})
```

```css
table, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="type">
  <p id="Mortgage Type">Mortgage Type</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="Type 2" checked/>Type 2<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="Type 3" checked/>Type 3<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="Type 5" checked/>Type 5<br>
</section>
<section id="fee">
  <p id="Fee">Fee</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="fee" checked/>Fee<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="nofee" checked/>No Fee<br>
</section>
<table>
  <thead><tr><td>Lender</td><td>Type</td><td>Fee</td></tr></thead>
  <tbody id='lenders'></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Not sure how the logic works on the 'fee' checkboxes. How would I add in different options for different fees for example? Looks like you have used a  > 0 logic rather than just show/hide based on actual value? Can I change this easily?

Comment: Given the checkboxes that you provided I assumed that you wanted to show the ones with fees and the ones without fees, I didn't realize that you wanted other options. What other options would you like?

Comment: Sorry, not your fault of course. I can add in the options, if you can steer me in direction of changing it to the same logic as first set. I have tried, but I mess up them working together for some reason?! - so numerical still, just say 0, 100, 200 for now

Answer (score 0):

If one of properties are checked row is showed

```js
var $products = $("#mortgagetable tbody > tr");
$products.hide();
var checked_arr = [];
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
  var $self = $(this);
  var checked = $self.prop("checked");
  var obj = $self.attr("data-type");
  if(checked){
        checked_arr.push(obj);
  }
  else
  {
  var poped = checked_arr.indexOf(obj);
        checked_arr.splice(poped,1);
  }
  $products.each(function(){//get tr data-types
    var to_split = $(this).attr("data-type");
 var attrs = [];
 attrs = to_split.split(",");
 
    for(var i=0; i<attrs.length; i++){
     if($self.attr("data-type") == attrs[i]){
   if(checked){//checked
      $(this).show();
      return;
   }
   else{
    var count = 0;
    $(attrs).each(function(){
     
     if(checked_arr.indexOf(this.toString()) > -1){ //unchecked and is not in 
      count++;      //checked attributes array
     } 
    });
    if(!count)
     $(this).hide();
   }
        }
 }
  });
});
```

```css
thead>tr{
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}

td,th{
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
th:nth-child(2n+1),td:nth-child(2n+1) {background: #CCC}{background-color: silver;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="repaymentcalc" id="calcform" action="">

<section id="type">

  <p id="Mortgage Type">Mortgage Type</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t2" id="t2"  data-type="type2" />Type 2<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t3" id="t3" data-type="type3" />Type 3<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t5" id="t5" data-type="type5"  />Type 5<br>

</section>

<section id="fee">

  <p id="Fee">Fee</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="fee" id="fee" data-type="fee" />Fee<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="nofee" id="nofee" data-type="nofee" />No Fee<br>

</section>

</form>

<table id="mortgagetable">
    
<thead>

<tr class="producthd"><th class="lenderhd">Lender</th><th class="typehd">Type</th><th class="feehd">Fee (£)</th></tr>

</thead>

<tbody>

<tr class="product" data-type="type2,fee"><td class="lender">Bank One<td class="t2">Type 2</td><td class="fee">1000</td></tr>
<tr class="product" data-type="type3,nofee"><td class="lender">Bank Two<td class="t3">Type 3</td><td class="nofee">None</td></tr>
<tr class="product" data-type="type5,nofee"><td class="lender">Bank Three<td class="t5">Type 5</td><td class="nofee">None</td></tr>

</tbody>

</table>
```